# Wordpress Custom Post Type with Custom Tags Array

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to create a custom post type with its own category type and tag type. I have the custom category working, but I am having some difficulty setting up the custom tag array properly.

I basically want to set up the tags for the post type so they are called services.

Here is what I have so far, but it generates an error and kills the instance.

```
<?php
// Adding Custom Post Type : Project
add_action('init', 'project_register');
function project_register() {
    $labels = array(
    'name'              => _x('Projects','Projects','Projects'),
    'singular_name'         => _x('Project','Project','Project'),
    'add_new'           => _x('Add New Project','Project Listing','Project'),
    'add_new_item'          => __('Add New Project','Project'),
    'edit_item'         => __('Edit Project','Project'),
    'new_item'          => __('New Project Post Item','Project'),
    'view_item'         => __('View Project Item','Project'),
    'search_items'          => __('Search Project','Project'),
    'not_found'         => __('Nothing found','Project'),
    'not_found_in_trash'        => __('Nothing found in Trash','Project'),
    'parent_item_colon'     => ''
    );

    $args = array(
    'labels'            => $labels,
    'public'            => true,
    'menu_position'         => 5,
    'exclude_from_search'       => true,
    'show_ui'           => true,
    'capability_type'       => 'post',
    'show_in_nav_menus'         => false,
    'hierarchical'          => false,
    'rewrite'           => array( 'with_front' => false ),
    'query_var'         => true,            
    'supports'          => array('title', 'editor', 'author', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail', 'comments'),
    'has_archive'           => true,
    'taxonomies'            => $tags,
); 
register_post_type( 'project' , $args ); 

    // Initialize New Taxonomy Labels  
    $labels = array(  
    'name'          => _x( 'Categories', 'taxonomy general name' ),  
    'singular_name'     => _x( 'Category', 'taxonomy singular name' ),  
    'search_items'      => __( 'Search Categories' ),  
    'all_items'         => __( 'All Categories' ),  
    'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Category' ),  
    'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Category:' ),  
    'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Categories' ),  
    'update_item'       => __( 'Update Category' ),  
    'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Category' ),  
    'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Category Name' ),  
    );  

   // Initialize New Taxonomy Tags
    $tags = array(  
    'name'          => _x( 'Services', 'taxonomy general name' ),  
    'singular_name'     => _x( 'Service', 'taxonomy singular name' ),  
    'search_items'      => __( 'Search Services' ),  
    'all_items'         => __( 'All Services' ),  
    'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Service' ),  
    'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Service:' ),  
    'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Services' ),  
    'update_item'       => __( 'Update Service' ),  
    'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Service' ),  
    'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Service Name' ),  
    ); 

    // Custom taxonomy for project categories 
    register_taxonomy('category-project', array('project'), array(  
    'hierarchical'      => true,  
    'labels'        => $labels,  
    'show_ui'       => true,  
    'query_var'         => true,  
    'rewrite'       => array( 'slug' => 'category-project' ),  
    )); 

    // Custom taxonomy for project categories 
    register_taxonomy('service-project', array('project'), array(  
    'hierarchical'      => true,  
    'labels'        => $tags,  
    'show_ui'       => true,  
    'query_var'         => true,  
    'rewrite'       => array( 'slug' => 'service-project' ),  
    ));
}


?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a few error. Please enable debug in wp-config

The one or two big issues I can see here is:

- You are using a undefined variable `$tags` in your post type arguments and in your last taxonomy. Where did you set that variable? It should also be in your function, not outside
- You have two instance of `$labels`, so the first taxonomy is confused about which one to use and fails.
- if you want to use a taxonomy as tags, set `hierarchial` to `false`. `true` will make the taxonomy to behave as categories

**EDIT**

Here is your code, working as it should

```
add_action('init', 'project_register');
function project_register() {
    $labels = array(
    'name'              => _x('Projects','Projects','Projects'),
    'singular_name'         => _x('Project','Project','Project'),
    'add_new'           => _x('Add New Project','Project Listing','Project'),
    'add_new_item'          => __('Add New Project','Project'),
    'edit_item'         => __('Edit Project','Project'),
    'new_item'          => __('New Project Post Item','Project'),
    'view_item'         => __('View Project Item','Project'),
    'search_items'          => __('Search Project','Project'),
    'not_found'         => __('Nothing found','Project'),
    'not_found_in_trash'        => __('Nothing found in Trash','Project'),
    'parent_item_colon'     => ''
    );

    $args = array(
    'labels'            => $labels,
    'public'            => true,
    'menu_position'         => 5,
    'exclude_from_search'       => true,
    'show_ui'           => true,
    'capability_type'       => 'post',
    'show_in_nav_menus'         => false,
    'hierarchical'          => false,
    'rewrite'           => array( 'with_front' => false ),
    'query_var'         => true,            
    'supports'          => array('title', 'editor', 'author', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail', 'comments'),
    'has_archive'           => true,
    'taxonomies'            => $tags,
); 
register_post_type( 'project' , $args ); 

    // Initialize New Taxonomy Labels  
    $labels = array(  
    'name'          => _x( 'Categories', 'taxonomy general name' ),  
    'singular_name'     => _x( 'Category', 'taxonomy singular name' ),  
    'search_items'      => __( 'Search Categories' ),  
    'all_items'         => __( 'All Categories' ),  
    'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Category' ),  
    'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Category:' ),  
    'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Categories' ),  
    'update_item'       => __( 'Update Category' ),  
    'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Category' ),  
    'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Category Name' ),  
    );  

   // Initialize New Taxonomy Tags
    $tags = array(  
    'name'          => _x( 'Services', 'taxonomy general name' ),  
    'singular_name'     => _x( 'Service', 'taxonomy singular name' ),  
    'search_items'      => __( 'Search Services' ),  
    'all_items'         => __( 'All Services' ),  
    'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Service' ),  
    'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Service:' ),  
    'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Services' ),  
    'update_item'       => __( 'Update Service' ),  
    'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Service' ),  
    'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Service Name' ),  
    ); 

    // Custom taxonomy for project categories 
    register_taxonomy('category-project', array('project'), array(  
    'hierarchical'      => true,  
    'labels'        => $labels,  
    'show_ui'       => true,  
    'query_var'         => true,  
    'rewrite'       => array( 'slug' => 'category-project' ),  
    )); 

    // Custom taxonomy for project categories 
    register_taxonomy('service-project', array('project'), array(  
    'hierarchical'      => false,  
    'labels'        => $tags,  
    'show_ui'       => true,  
    'query_var'         => true,  
    'rewrite'       => array( 'slug' => 'service-project' ),  
    ));
}
```

Comment: sorry the two instances of labels was a typo in the question.

Comment: OK, I've tested your code. It works fine with my suggestions. You have to set `hierarchial` to false in your `service-project` for them to work as tags, and not categories

Comment: ok that seems to work great, thanks. When I use it, I am seeing an error though, any ideas? Will go look at that line
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/usr/public_html/wp-includes/post.php on line 1350

Comment: I have tested the code again with post etc, not getting any debug errors on my side. Testing on wordpress v3.9.1

Comment: it seemed to be because of the     
'taxonomies'            => $tags, line 
I removed that and it works perfectly now, with no error. Thanks a lot for the help; much appreciated :-)

Comment: That line tickled me, but funnily though, I got no debug errors. Funny how things work though. Glad your problem is solved